# reading and storing data in SOAP UI

Tags: sql, soapui

I am new to SOAPUI.
I know it is possible to query into DB.

But how i can read and store number of records?

i want to check the record are generated are not same 
e.g
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3

all records should be unique.

Thanks

Comment: Try providing some more context as to what exactly you are trying to achieve. What exactly is your test case?

Comment: I wanted to check 1 field in the DB.all created records are not same

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

To get the count of duplicates you can use the below query on JDBC request in Soap UI or you can try in Groovy script editor.

SELECT FIRST_NAME,COUNT(FIRST_NAME) AS NumOccurrences FROM consumer GROUP BY FIRST_NAME HAVING ( COUNT(FIRST_NAME) > 1 )

If it brings out results then the test case should fail. If the query does not yield result then the test case is pass...